# The Schur Theorem

Tags: group-theory

The Schur Theorem: if $\left\vert G:Z\left( G\right) \right\vert $ is finite,
then $G^{\prime }$ is finite.

My question is: if $1\not=N\trianglelefteq G$ such that $\left\vert G:NZ\left(
G\right) \right\vert $ is finite, is there some information on $G^{\prime }$
or

some finiteness conditions involving $G^{\prime }?$

Comment: Well any such condition would have to include $N$ somewhere. It would follow from the quoted result of Schur that $G^{\prime}/(G^{\prime} \cap N)$ is finite. On the other hand, taking $N = G$ tells you nothing really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $N=G$ this does not give you any information to draw a conclusion on finiteness. You can approach this from another angle. 
**Theorem** If $|G: \zeta_i(G)|$ < $\infty$ then $|G^{i}|$ < $\infty$. Here $\zeta_i(G)$ is the i-th term of the *upper central series* of $G$ (by convention $Z(G) = \zeta_1(G)$) and $G^{i}$ is the i-th term of the *derived series* of $G$. 
Proof: induction on $i$, let me give you the first step:  $G/\zeta_2(G) \cong (G/Z(G))/Z(G/Z(G))$ is finite, implies $(G/Z(G))’$ is finite. But $(G/Z(G))’ \cong G’/(G’ \cap Z(G))$. And of course $G’ \cap Z(G) \subseteq Z(G’)$. We conclude that $|G’/Z(G’)|$ < $\infty$. Again Schur’s Theorem gives you that $G''$ is a finite group.$\Box$

Comment: Lima: Very good!

Comment: I just looked it up and remembered it when writing down the above Theorem. Reinhold Baer proved something stronger in 1945, namely that if $|G/\zeta_i(G)| < \infty$, then $|\gamma_{i+1}(G)|<\infty$, that is the $(i+1)$-th term of the *lower central series* of $G$. Note that $G^i \subseteq \gamma_{i+1}(G)$. So the result of Baer implies the Theorem! Conversely, Philip Hall proved that if $|\gamma_i(G)| < \infty$, then $|G/\zeta_{2i}(G)| < \infty$!