# $G$ finite-by-abelian implies $G/Z_2(G)$ finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite-by-abelian group (i.e. $G$ has a finite commutator subgroup). Then $C:=C_G(G')$ is such that $G/C$ is finite and $C$ is nilpotent of class at most $2$. But why $G$ over the second center is finite?

Comment: The second center of $G$ as I mentioned in the final question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a famous paper by Philip Hall, *Finite-by-nilpotent groups*, Proc. Cambridge Phil. Soc. **52** (1956), 611-616, where he proves that if $\gamma_2(G)=G'$ is finite, then $G/\zeta_2(G)$ is finite.

This result of Philip Hall is part of research and results on the converse of Schur's Theorem (if $G/\zeta(G)$ is finite then $\gamma_2(G)$ is finite). See also my remarks [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182997/the-schur-theorem/183160#183160).

Comment: Oh, ok. I thinked that the result was easier to show. Thanks!